# Double click a row in Sencha Test

Tags: extjs, sencha-test, sencha-test-2.1

How to double click a grid row using Sencha Test Framework ?

So far I'm able to reference the row and execute a click but I don't see a way to perform a double click (doing a click 2 times doesn't work either as a double click)

http://docs.sencha.com/sencha_test/2.1.0/api/ST.future.Row.html#method-click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 ST.play([
            {type: "dblclick", target: row}
 ]);
```

row being something like this:

```
return this.grid().rowWith('name', 'Value of the name').visible();
```

got it from here:

https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?334035-Double-Clicking-on-a-grid-row&p=1186355#post1186355